# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken only called if user allows push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Currently the callback `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is only being called when the users clicks 'allow' after `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }` is called.

I believe there should be a way to always get the users APN token, but currently I am only getting it if the user allows push notifications. Is there a way to always get the APN token even if the user does not allow?

The intention is to user the token for silent notifications even if they did not allow notifications to be displayed

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    firstLaunchCheck()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

// Called when APNs has assigned the device a unique token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string
    let passedTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    //store token in db
    print("APNs device token: \(passedTokenString)")
}
```

Comment: Just call `registerForRemoteNotifications` outside the completion closure of `requestAuthorization`

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe it is currently outside the `requestAuthorization` closure? If I do something like 
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}` then `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` does not get called at all

Comment: Oh right, I missed the }.  You do not need to request permissions if you only want silent notifications. Have you enabled push notifications in the project capabilities tab in Xcode?

Comment: I have, and the push notifications work fine when I am able to get the apn token (basically only when the user hits allow)

Comment: Have you implemented the [didFailToRegister](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622962-application) function? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Paulw11 I did, but it doesn't get called either. Seems like nothing is being called unless they explicitly allow notifications for some reason

Comment: @inSo23 in apple document mention that you can get device token only only when user authorize push permission. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications?language=objc)

Comment: @chiragshah it says in that document that you can still deliver silent notifications if the user does not authorize push notifications. I was able to do so and am now getting the token regardless of what the user selects

Comment: @inSo23 ohh i do not know about this. I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out after hours of frustration. I simply had to enable "Remote notifications" under Background Modes in the capabilities sections of Xcode

[image]

Now I get the APN token regardless if user allows push notifications or not